# How to hide column(s) in a table without hiding the column(s) on the sheet containing the table

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I have a simple table called 'Parts' with column headers named A-1, A-2, A-3, etc.
I have a button set up to try to hide a selected column. Lets say column 'A-3'.
When I select the button, the table column is hidden, however, the column on the worksheet is also hidden.
Here is my code.

```
Private Sub TestButton1_Click()
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Parts")
        .ListColumns("A-3").DataBodyRange.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    End With
    
End Sub
```

How do I not hide the worksheet column?

Thanks.
Rich

Comment: You can't...... You can only hide an entire row or an entire column. Doesn't matter if you are working with a table or not.

Comment: Well, that is not going to solve my goal. I would be having data to the left of the table as well as above the table. So, if I hide the table columns, it will hide the data above.
Do you know a way to echo one third of my table into the view space on my working sheet so that the user can change his third of the table and see the totals above the table data change?